# Unable to match blank spaces regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a regex criteria in json schema validation where a string should not accept blank spaces if entire string consists of blank spaces or blank spaces are between any input, but should accept if there are any blank spaces before and after characters, numbers or any special characters

Say

```
str = "  "
```

should not be accepted

or

```
str = "ab cd"
```

should not be accepted.
But

```
str = "abcd  "
```

should be accepted
or

```
str = "  abcd"
```

should be accepted.

I have used below regex pattern

```
"pattern":"^[^\\s]*$"
```

But this is not accepting any blank spaces in the string. All the above scenarios mentioned is showing invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
"pattern":"^\\s*\\S+\\s*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSq6CV/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.